# navigationItem.title does not exist? with splitviewcontroller (ipad)

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

how do you write a title or add a barbuttonitem in the navigation bar with a split view controller-based project?

i tried `self.navigationItem.title = @"allo";` in viewDidLoad, but only the popover button is shown in the nav bar.

Am i missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the detail view controller for this method.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController *)pc
```

You can add a UIBarButtonItem to the items array that the above method provides.  Also take a look at this link [Fixing the UISplitViewController Template](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/)

It will show you how to further customize the stock UISplitViewController template.